# Mongo upsert - specify _id type

Tags: mongodb, updates, upsert

When I run an upsert query, I'd like newly generated documents to have an `_id` of type string instead of a Mongo Id. It it possible to do that? Currently I'm doing

```
var data = { test: 1234 };
edgesCollection.update(data, { $set: data }, { upsert: true });
```

But this creates a document like

```
 { _id: { [String: '583e1ecd39ff3ba3228523ce'] _str: '583e1ecd39ff3ba3228523ce' },
test: 1234 }
```

While I'd like to get

```
{ _id: '583e1ecd39ff3ba3228523ce', test: 1234 }
```

Comment: try it with `replace`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `$setOnInsert` operator within the update, for example:

```
var data = { test: 1234 };
db.edgesCollection.update(data, { $set: data, $setOnInsert: {_id : "my string id"} }, { upsert: true });

> db.edgesCollection.find()
{ "_id" : "my string id", "test" : 1234 }
```

See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/ for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the _id field. If you don't specify it will be auto generated. For this to work you have to use insert instead of update (check it out :-) I really advise you to leave the _id as a ObjectId.